# how to make .doc/.docx file from HTML (as string)?

Tags: php, html, docx, doc

i have a srting in html format like bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"><head><style><!--

                    /*paged media */ div.header {display: none }
                    div.footer {display: none } /*@media print { */


                    @page { size: A4; margin: 10%; @top-center {
                    content: element(header) } @bottom-center {
                    content: element(footer) } }


                    /*font definitions*/

                    /*element styles*/ .del
                    {text-decoration:line-through;color:red;}

                          .ins {text-decoration:none;background:#c0ffc0;padding:1px;}



                    /* Word style definitions */

 /* TABLE STYLES */ 

 /* PARAGRAPH STYLES */ 
.DocDefaults {display:block;space-after: 4mm;line-height: 115%;font-family: Calibri;font-size: 11.0pt;}
.Normal {display:block;}

 /* CHARACTER STYLES */ .DefaultParagraphFont {display:inline;}


                    /* TABLE CELL STYLES */
                    --></style><script type="text/javascript">

                function toggleDiv(divid){
                    if(document.getElementById(divid).style.display == 'none'){
                        document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'block';
                    }else{
                        document.getElementById(divid).style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }

            </script></head><body>

  <!-- userBodyTop goes here -->



  <div class="document">

  <p class="Normal DocDefaults "><span style="font-weight: bold;">Hi</span><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;"> </span>[name]<span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">. </span><span style="font-weight: bold;color: #FF0000;">your</span><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;"> ac is</span><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;"> </span>[acc_no]<span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">, and </span><span style="font-weight: bold;color: #FF0000;">your</span><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;"> password </span><span style="white-space:pre-wrap;">is </span>[password].</p>

  <p class="Normal DocDefaults ">Thanks you.</p></div>







  <!-- userBodyTail goes here -->

  </body></html>
```

i want to make a .doc or .docx file using this string. the doc or docx should save in directory and the link in DB for download.what to do?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  Also have you seen http://www.phpdocx.com/?

Comment: phpdocx needs pdf and zip module in server. but i am not able to install those modules. so i am serching for core php code. the above string can be export as doc and user can save it. but my requirement is to save it in server directory and link of directory to DB for later download

Comment: when i am displaying html (doc saved as web page) in browser the style of doc is showing properly. when i export it to doc again the style is not showing properly. what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
/* HTML to Microsoft Word Export
* This code demonstrates how to export an html element to Microsoft Word
* with CSS styles to set page orientation and paper size.
* Tested with Word 2010, 2013 and FireFox, Chrome, Opera, IE10-11
* Fails in legacy browsers (IE<10) that lack window.Blob object
*/
function saveDoc() {

  if (!window.Blob) {
    alert('Your legacy browser does not support this action.');
    return;
  }

  var html, link, blob, url, css;

  // EU A4 use: size: 841.95pt 595.35pt;
  // US Letter use: size:11.0in 8.5in;

  css = ('\
   <style>\
   @page WordSection1{size: 841.95pt 595.35pt;mso-page-orientation: portrait;}\
   div.WordSection1 {page: WordSection1;}\
   h1 {font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif; font-size: 16pt;}\
   p {font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif; font-size: 14pt;}\
   </style>\
  ');

  var rightAligned = document.getElementsByClassName("sm-align-right");
  for (var i=0, max=rightAligned.length; i < max; i++) {
    rightAligned[i].style = "text-align: right;"
  }

  var centerAligned = document.getElementsByClassName("sm-align-center");
  for (var i=0, max=centerAligned.length; i < max; i++) {
    centerAligned[i].style = "text-align: center;"
  }

  html = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
  html = '\
  <html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">\
  <head>\
    <title>Document Title</title>\
    <xml>\
      <w:worddocument xmlns:w="#unknown">\
        <w:view>Print</w:view>\
        <w:zoom>90</w:zoom>\
        <w:donotoptimizeforbrowser />\
      </w:worddocument>\
    </xml>\
  </head>\
  <body lang=RU-ru style="tab-interval:.5in">\
    <div class="Section1">' + html + '</div>\
  </body>\
  </html>'

  blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', css + html], {
    type: 'application/msword'
  });

  url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link = document.createElement('A');
  link.href = url;

  filename = 'filename';

  // Set default file name.
  // Word will append file extension - do not add an extension here.
  link.download = filename;   

  document.body.appendChild(link);

  if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename + '.doc'); // IE10-11
  } else {
    link.click(); // other browsers
  }

  document.body.removeChild(link);
};
```

Comment: Works like charm. Just a quick remark as for today's date, **05-12-2019**, the `navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob()` is deprecated and not advisable for prodiction environment (see Mozilla's Docs). And a quick question: how do we achieve the same result for `docx` files?

Answer (score 0):

I am an iOs developer, ButI am able to convert html into .docx.
Please replace & add following code into your HTML file & please change file extension to .dcox/,doc

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\"  \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\"><html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:w=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\"                xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><body>"
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Can you make a web page display a .docx file. Is this what you are trying to do.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working; I am able to open doc file but not docx file sicne files for the latter turn out corrupted